# FireFox not interpretting CORS headers correctly?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I just updated my FF in Mac to Quantum 58.0. And the javascript component in our page is sending a request to our API which sends back the following headers in response

```
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 3
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Wed, 24 Jan 2018 16:52:20 GMT
x-amzn-RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxx
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

However, the following `DELETE` method request is blocked with this error message

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://myapi/myresource. (Reason: Did not find method in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Methods’).

Isn't FF interpreting '*' as everything? Chrome is doing this request correctly. Any helps/clues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you testing with?

Comment: Forgot to include my OPTIONS request headers   Host: myapi
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Access-Control-Request-Method: DELETE
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,x-api-key
Origin: https://mypage.com
Connection: keep-alive